# Embedded tweets of twitter doesn't rendered in InnerHTML after sanitized in Angular 8 Application

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter, innerhtml

> The HTML string comes from server contains embedded tweets which is not rendered in InnerHTML after sanitizing. Any solutions appreciated

My .ts Code

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'DemoDynamicMarkupTwitterCode';

  myDynamicMarkup: string = "<p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"text-align: justify;\">\n\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">&lt;blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\"&gt;&lt;p lang=\"en\" dir=\"ltr\"&gt;Every good conversation starts with good listening. And Listening becomes interesting when you are in front of this legend. pic.twitter.com/ZxiyR2q9Ko&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&amp;mdash; Yuzvendra Chahal (@yuzi_chahal) &lt;a href=\"https://twitter.com/yuzi_chahal/status/1156792063761479136?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw\"&gt;August 1, 2019&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt; &lt;script async src=\"https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</p>\n\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">&nbsp;</p>"

  constructor(public share: ShareService, private renderer2: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

--- pipe to sanitize---
`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(html): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
```

`

--- HTML file

```
<div [innerHTML]="myDynamicMarkup | safeHtml"></div>
```

I want the tweet to be rendered inside the page.. Anyone let us know with any working solution or what is the workaround and how this could be achieved. About the HTML String, Its received from server during the web service call, the twitter tweet could be part of inside as the html string as embedded and its created through rich text editor of a separate application and stored in database..

Answer (score 1):

```
<div [innerHTML]="myDynamicMarkup | safeHtml"></div>
```

You have to use your custom pipe.

Comment: That was a mistake in my question. I corrected it.. Even after using the custom pipe its still not rendering